# R plot axes don't meet and data extends beyond them

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a VERY basic plot in R, and I'd like to solve two issues. Here is the code which produces the plot:

```
plot(o,n,bty="n",pch=21,cex=1.5,bg="gray",xlab="y",ylab="x",lwd=2)
```

And, here's the plot
[image]

There are two unwanted behaviors of this plot that I'm trying to fix. And I don't know how to do either one (nor do I understand why R doesn't do these things already...)

1. The X and Y axes do not meet. There is a gap near the origin in this plot. I want to remove that. The axes should touch, just like any other graph.
2. The data extends past the axis is both the X and Y direction. This clearly is unwanted. How can I fix this without having to manually make my own axis. Seems like there should be something more intuitive here.

Comment: a more informative title (e.g. "axis problems with basic scatterplot") might be nice ...

Comment: A word of advice (from my advisor, actually): never write things like "clearly" or "should" or "just like any other"; there will always be someone who either disagrees or doesn't think it's clear or obvious.  In this case, it rubs those people the wrong way and makes it harder to get assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `bty="l".`
2. You may also want to use something like:

   ```
   xlim=c(0.02, 0.24), ylim=c(0.02, 0.24)
   ```

if you don't like the default limits of your two axes.

In general, check out `?par` for guidance on both of these and many other options.

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving out `bty="n"` or replacing it by `bty="L"` if you really do not want a box with edges above or on the right